# Transferring Data to Excel

Tags: vba

I have the following code to transfer code to excel file:

```
Dim SaveAsStr As String
    Dim appXL As Excel.Application
    Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wst As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim startcell As Range
    DoCmd.RunMacro "Guardarmcr"

      Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      appXL.Visible = True
      Set wbk = appXL.Workbooks.Add
      Set wst = wbk.Worksheets(1)
      Set startcell = Range("D16")

      Set cn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
      Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
       Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
       Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset


      With rs
        Set .ActiveConnection = cn
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM ExcelTitulotbl"
        .Open
      End With

      With rs1
        Set .ActiveConnection = cn
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM Excelotptbl"
        .Open
      End With

      With rs2

        Set .ActiveConnection = cn
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM ExcelEDTUDCtbl"
        .Open

      End With


      With wst
        '.QueryTables.Add Connection:=rs, Destination:=.Range("A1")
        '.QueryTables(1).Refresh


         .QueryTables.Add Connection:=rs1, Destination:=.Range("d16")
        .QueryTables(1).Refresh


         .Range("A16").EntireRow.Delete
         .Range("e2").Font.Bold = True
         .Range("e2").Font.Name = "Calibri"
          .Range("e2").Font.Size = 14

        .Range("e2") = "VALORACION"
        .Range("D5") = "Descripción"
        .Range("j5") = "Profesional Colaborador"
        .Range("j6") = "Profesional Chilectra"
        .Range("e5") = rs("proyectoMain")
        .Range("k5") = rs("Empleado")
        .Range("k6") = rs("chilectramain")

        .Range("B15") = "Recargo"
        .Range("D15") = "Número"
        .Range("E15") = "Apdto"
         .Range("F14") = "Tipo"
        .Range("F15") = "Ocurrencia"
        .Range("g15") = "Especialidad"
         .Range("h14") = "Tipo"
         .Range("h15") = "Activo"


          TotalE

      End With
     wbk.Saved = True
     Set wks = Nothing
             Set wbk = Nothing

             Set appXL = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Most of it works all right but if I try to run the command a Second time the worksheet opens but the vba fails showing a 1004 error. It has something to do with `LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. If I quit the form and enter it again it works the first time but not a second.

Will appreciate some help on this, thanks.

Comment: Las part of code is:

    Sub TotalE()
    
    Dim LR As Long
       
      LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("D" & LR + 2) = LR + 2
        
        End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling the TotalE sub routine, but in it you are not telling the range explicitly what workbook to use.
Activeworkbook.Range() may be better or when you add the workbook, capture the name and pass it to the sub routine.

Strange, but your only calculating the last row in column E and putting that value + 2 into column D two rows down.

All you really need is this code to replace your call to TotalE:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
End Sub
```